# Generate PDF and excel sheet, but in excel it neither open nor option to save ....(as like in laravel)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

How to generate excel sheet in node js open directly or save in system, not in the project directory.

```
For Excel 
exports.excel = function (req, res) {
    var fs =require('fs');
    var excel = require('excel4node');
    var workbook = new excel.Workbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
    var worksheet2 = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 2');
    worksheet.cell(1, 1).string('content for display');
    workbook.write('report.xlsx');
    workbook.co(function(ok){
        if (!ok) 
            workbook.cancel();
        else
            console.log('congratulations, your workbook created');
    });
    //res.download();
    //workbook.close();
    //res.redirect('/invoice/list');

};
```

Comment: Try using *process.chdir* to change directory where excel-file should be generated.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh I'm not using a directory to save this excel sheet, it automatically generates sheet in project root directory, i want to directly open excel sheet or download in the system path by hitting URL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream content of `report.xlsx` to web-browser, then you need to add following lines after `console.log('congratulations, your workbook created')`:

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'report.xlsx');
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
var ct = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';

res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': ct,
    'Content-Length': stat.size
});

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
readStream.pipe(res);
```